# How to make a grouped BarChart with ios-charts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) library.

I would like to group my inverter values so that each year is one group. Unfortunately, the number of monthly values per year may vary.

My data json looks like this:

```
{"monthlyData":[{"ERTRAG":"30.2989999055862","MONAT":"2","JAHR":"2016"},{"ERTRAG":"154.897000223398","MONAT":"1","JAHR":"2016"},{"ERTRAG":"141.996000155807","MONAT":"12","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"135.449000149965","MONAT":"11","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"319.437000751495","MONAT":"10","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"483.369997739792","MONAT":"9","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"698.112997770309","MONAT":"8","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"771.764000892639","MONAT":"7","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"736.611003398895","MONAT":"6","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"737.237999916077","MONAT":"5","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"720.181995391846","MONAT":"4","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"484.979001283646","MONAT":"3","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"249.974001646042","MONAT":"2","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"92.8830004036427","MONAT":"1","JAHR":"2015"},{"ERTRAG":"52.7970000207424","MONAT":"12","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"181.025999426842","MONAT":"11","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"332.789002537727","MONAT":"10","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"482.244999885559","MONAT":"9","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"602.811999320984","MONAT":"8","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"699.872003316879","MONAT":"7","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"828.212007522583","MONAT":"6","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"679.010004997253","MONAT":"5","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"635.115998744965","MONAT":"4","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"559.617002010345","MONAT":"3","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"265.135001063347","MONAT":"2","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"165.272998273373","MONAT":"1","JAHR":"2014"},{"ERTRAG":"134.578999936581","MONAT":"12","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"153.774000287056","MONAT":"11","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"321.733997344971","MONAT":"10","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"482.768000483513","MONAT":"9","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"692.864000797272","MONAT":"8","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"846.429007053375","MONAT":"7","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"709.758005619049","MONAT":"6","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"532.493996858597","MONAT":"5","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"462.539998054504","MONAT":"4","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"419.105004012585","MONAT":"3","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"143.189998820424","MONAT":"2","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"78.720000628382","MONAT":"1","JAHR":"2013"},{"ERTRAG":"90.1430006623268","MONAT":"12","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"155.483000457287","MONAT":"11","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"348.231998205185","MONAT":"10","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"598.037001848221","MONAT":"9","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"729.740003108978","MONAT":"8","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"676.923998832703","MONAT":"7","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"694.879002094269","MONAT":"6","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"811.281997680664","MONAT":"5","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"489.765002369881","MONAT":"4","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"538.866001605988","MONAT":"3","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"277.856996208429","MONAT":"2","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"155.854999214411","MONAT":"1","JAHR":"2012"},{"ERTRAG":"148.157999750227","MONAT":"12","JAHR":"2011"},{"ERTRAG":"230.409998774529","MONAT":"11","JAHR":"2011"}]}
```

I tried the following:

```
var months = Array<String>()
var years = Array<String>()
var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
var dataSets: [BarChartDataSet] = []
var overallSum = 0.0
var year = 2010 //monthlyValues[0].year
var count = 0
var chartDataSet: BarChartDataSet?

for i in 0..<monthlyValues.count {
  // if year is different, create new barchartdataset
  if monthlyValues[i].year != year {
    years.append("\(monthlyValues[i].year)")
    chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "\(year)")
    chartDataSet!.colors = [UIColor.whiteColor()]
    dataSets.append(chartDataSet!)
    year = monthlyValues[i].year
    dataEntries = []
    //months = []
    count = 0
  }
  months.append("\(monthlyValues[i].month)")
  overallSum += monthlyValues[i].amount

  let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: monthlyValues[i].amount, xIndex: count)
  count++
  dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}
let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSets: dataSets)
self.barChartView.data = chartData
```

This results in five series with the right year labels in the legend but there is no group separator in the chart and also the number of bars per year is either 4 or 5 (expected = 12).

Thanks for any hint on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got something wrong here. Right now you are creating a new `DataSet` for every year.

What you need to do is create as many `DataSets` as you want bars per group where one DataSet represents one bar in each group. (e.g. DataSet 1 represents every first bar of a group, DataSet 2 every second bar of a group, ...)

As an example, imagine a chart like this with 4 groups of 3 bars per group. Each group represents one year.

> **||| ||| ||| |||**

- The setup shown above requires 3 DataSets (one for each group)
- Entries in the same group have the same x-index (e.g. in the first group all have x-index 0)
- It consists of a total of 12 entries
- Each DataSet contains 4 entries with Entry x-indices ranging from 0 to 3

[Here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Demos/MultipleBarChartViewController.swift) you can find an example of the scenario described above and check out the [documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/).

Comment: How the entire data set (4 entries) or a group will be tappable instead individual bars of the group ?

Answer (score 46):

[image]

```
let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0]
    let unitsBought = [10.0, 14.0, 60.0, 13.0, 2.0]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            barChartView.delegate = self
            barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
            barChartView.chartDescription?.text = "sales vs bought "


            //legend
            let legend = barChartView.legend
            legend.enabled = true
            legend.horizontalAlignment = .right
            legend.verticalAlignment = .top
            legend.orientation = .vertical
            legend.drawInside = true
            legend.yOffset = 10.0;
            legend.xOffset = 10.0;
            legend.yEntrySpace = 0.0;


            let xaxis = barChartView.xAxis
            xaxis.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
            xaxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
            xaxis.labelPosition = .bottom
            xaxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
            xaxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:self.months)
            xaxis.granularity = 1


            let leftAxisFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            leftAxisFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1

            let yaxis = barChartView.leftAxis
            yaxis.spaceTop = 0.35
            yaxis.axisMinimum = 0
            yaxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

            barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
           //axisFormatDelegate = self

            setChart()
        }

 func setChart() {
        barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        var dataEntries1: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<self.months.count {

            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i) , y: self.unitsSold[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)

            let dataEntry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i) , y: self.self.unitsBought[i])
            dataEntries1.append(dataEntry1)

            //stack barchart
            //let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues:  [self.unitsSold[i],self.unitsBought[i]], label: "groupChart")



        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Unit sold")
        let chartDataSet1 = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries1, label: "Unit Bought")

        let dataSets: [BarChartDataSet] = [chartDataSet,chartDataSet1]
        chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 126/255, blue: 34/255, alpha: 1)]
        //chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        //let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)


        let groupSpace = 0.3
        let barSpace = 0.05
        let barWidth = 0.3
        // (0.3 + 0.05) * 2 + 0.3 = 1.00 -> interval per "group" 

        let groupCount = self.months.count
        let startYear = 0


        chartData.barWidth = barWidth;
        barChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = Double(startYear)
        let gg = chartData.groupWidth(groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
        print("Groupspace: \(gg)")
        barChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(startYear) + gg * Double(groupCount)

        chartData.groupBars(fromX: Double(startYear), groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
        //chartData.groupWidth(groupSpace: groupSpace, barSpace: barSpace)
        barChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()

        barChartView.data = chartData






        //background color
        barChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 195/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1)

        //chart animation
        barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5, yAxisDuration: 1.5, easingOption: .linear)


    }
```

Comment: i have four set of data...this code works perfact with 3 set...what should i change to meet n no of group requirement?

Comment: if you have noticed in above code in function chart. There is let

 groupSpace = 0.3
 let barSpace = 0.05
 let barWidth = 0.3
 // (0.3 + 0.05) * 2 + 0.3 = 1.00 -> interval per "group" 
which will make equation (groupSpace * barSpace) * n + groupSpace = 1

you need to play around this equation for n number of bars

Comment: thnx for replay....i am using this for 4 bars (0.2 + 0.03) * 4 + 0.08 = 1.00...but it is not working...i can only see 3 bars, second last is missing

Comment: use this equation (groupSpace * barSpace) * n + groupSpace = 1.   From your requirement it should be (0.176 + 0.03) * 4 +0.176 = 1.0

Comment: thnx...it works...will you please tell me how did you calculate it? how can i find exact value

Comment: You need to solve above equation. With n=4 and barSpace=0.03

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144898/discussion-between-black-tiger-and-h-raval).

Comment: @BlackTiger will you please check my issue at https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2481

Comment: I am successful in creating the chart but i want it horizontally.how can i achieve it?

Comment: @RajanTwanabashu: please check this issues and please help me out in this. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2481
Thanx in advance..

Comment: all the values that i have in month are shown on the table! amny Idea? from elemnt 6 to the end is used and set from group 1 to where the months elements get finished

Answer (score 2):

if you have noticed in above code in function chart. There is  let

```
 groupSpace = 0.3
 let barSpace = 0.05
 let barWidth = 0.3
 // (0.3 + 0.05) * 2 + 0.3 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"
```

which will make equation 
**(groupSpace * barSpace)  * n + groupSpace = 1**

you need to play around this equation for n number of bars

Answer (score 2):

I've tried Rajan Twanabashu solution, but it was almost the good one. Maybe it has changed since, I don't know.

Here's what I've done, after I found the *groupWidth* function in the *BarDataChart* file from **Charts**.

[groupWidth function declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdzHR.png)

`let groupSpace = 1 - n * (barWidth + barSpace)`

Hope it could help

Comment: Hello Alex, your answer doesn't bring anything new to the table as there are already accepted answer and some very descriptive high voted ones too.

Comment: Please do not include links to screenshots showing code only. copy-paste the code instead.

Comment: Well, this answer didn’t work for me but the one I wrote did. It may be an update ? So where could I show my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

After diving in this equation "(0.3 + 0.05) * 2 + 0.3 = 1.00" to work on variant amount of grouping I got:

```
let n = Double(data.dataSets.count)
let groupSpace = 0.0031 * n
let barSpace = 0.002 * n
let barWidth = (1 - (n * barSpace) - groupSpace) / n
```

What is varying is barWidth.

[image: With 15:]

[image: With 4:]

Comment: The problem here is if is only one group, I think I will solve with a simple bar.