# Multiple bar chart group spacing issue

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I'm working with an application, where charts are used to display reports.
I use https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts. here im able to bind data, but the groups are placed in wrong position with respect to x-axis. Please refer the image displayed below.[image: The bars placed in the charts are not grouped properly]

Please help me to group the bars properly.

Comment: Put your code first to see what you have done.

Comment: @RajAggrawal Please check in the answer field. I was not able to post here.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294076/how-to-make-a-grouped-barchart-with-ios-charts

Comment: If the BAR's count is within 4, they are grouped in correct order. If the BAR's  count exceeds 4, they get placed beyond the groups position. Please help on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)setDataCount:(int)count range:(double)range
{
    float groupSpace = 0.08f;
    float barSpace = 0.03f;
    float barWidth = 0.2f;
    // (0.2 + 0.03) * 4 + 0.08 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"

    NSMutableArray *yVals1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals5 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals6 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals7 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals8 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *yVals9 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   // double randomMultiplier = range * 100000.f;

    int groupCount = count+1;
    int startYear = 1980;
    //int endYear = startYear + groupCount;

    //NSArray *getFloatingVal = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedFloatValTrend"];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {


        if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Total Production"] && flagTotal==true) {
        [yVals1 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"totalProd"] objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]]];
        }

         if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"eb/100sh"] && flageb==true) {
        [yVals2 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"ebPerHunderedSh"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]];
         }

         if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Production Efficiency"] && flagProduction==true) {
        [yVals3 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"productionEfficiency"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]];
         }

        if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"End Break count"] && flagEnd==true) {
        [yVals4 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"endBreakCount"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]];
         }

         if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Rouge Spindle Count"] && flagRouge==true) {
        [yVals5 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"rougeCount"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]];
         }

         if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"No of Doff"] && flagNoDoff==true) {
        [yVals6 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"numberofDoffs"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]];
         }

         if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Startup Breaks"] && flagStartup==true) {
        [yVals7 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"startupBreak"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]];
         }

         if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Slip Count"] && flagSlip==true) {
        [yVals8 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"slipCount"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]];
         }

         if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Idle Count"] && flagIdle==true) {
        [yVals9 addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc]
                           initWithX:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]
                           y:[[[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"idleCount"] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]]];
         }



        NSString *dateStr = [[getDataToLoadChart valueForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:i];

        // Convert string to date object
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
        [xVals addObject:date];
    }

    BarChartDataSet *set1 = nil, *set2 = nil, *set3 = nil, *set4 = nil ,*set5 = nil, *set6 = nil, *set7 = nil, *set8 = nil,*set9 = nil;
    _chartView.data=nil;
    if (_chartView.data.dataSetCount > 0)
    {
        set1 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[0];
        set2 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[1];
        set3 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[2];
        set4 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[3];
        set5 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[4];
        set6 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[5];
        set7 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[6];
        set8 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[7];
        set9 = (BarChartDataSet *)_chartView.data.dataSets[8];
        set1.values = yVals1;
        set2.values = yVals2;
        set3.values = yVals3;
        set4.values = yVals4;
        set5.values = yVals5;
        set6.values = yVals6;
        set7.values = yVals7;
        set8.values = yVals8;
        set9.values = yVals9;



        BarChartData *data = _chartView.barData;

        _chartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = startYear;
        _chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = [data groupWidthWithGroupSpace:groupSpace barSpace: barSpace] * _sliderX.value + startYear;
        [data groupBarsFromX: startYear groupSpace: groupSpace barSpace: barSpace];

        [_chartView.data notifyDataChanged];
        [_chartView notifyDataSetChanged];
    }
    else
    {
    NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (count>0) {



    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Total Production"] && flagTotal==true) {
        set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals1 label:@"Total Production"];
        [set1 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:104/255.f green:241/255.f blue:175/255.f alpha:1.f]];
        [dataSets addObject:set1];
    }

    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"eb/100sh"] && flageb==true) {
        set2 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals2 label:@"eb/100sh"];
        [set2 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:164/255.f green:228/255.f blue:251/255.f alpha:1.f]];
        [dataSets addObject:set2];
    }

    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Production Efficiency"] && flagProduction==true) {
        set3 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals3 label:@"Production Efficiency"];
        [set3 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:242/255.f green:247/255.f blue:158/255.f alpha:1.f]];
        [dataSets addObject:set3];
    }

    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"End Break count"] && flagEnd==true) {
        set4 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals4 label:@"End Break count"];
        [set4 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.f green:102/255.f blue:0/255.f alpha:1.f]];
         [dataSets addObject:set4];
    }

    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Rouge Spindle Count"] && flagRouge==true) {
        set5 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals5 label:@"Rouge Spindle Count"];
        [set5 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.f green:102/255.f blue:204/255.f alpha:1.f]];
        [dataSets addObject:set5];
    }

    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"No of Doff"] && flagNoDoff==true) {
        set6 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals6 label:@"No of Doff"];
        [set6 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.f green:0/255.f blue:0/255.f alpha:1.f]];
        [dataSets addObject:set6];
    }

    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Startup Breaks"] && flagStartup==true) {
        set7 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals7 label:@"Startup Breaks"];
        [set7 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.f green:255/255.f blue:0/255.f alpha:1.f]];
         [dataSets addObject:set7];
    }

    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Slip Count"] && flagSlip==true) {
        set8 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:yVals8 label:@"Slip Count"];
        [set8 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:153/255.f green:153/255.f blue:102/255.f alpha:1.f]];
         [dataSets addObject:set8];
    }

    if ([arrForChartsDisplay containsObject:@"Idle Count"] && flagIdle==true) {
        set9 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc]initWithValues:yVals9 label:@"Idle Count"];
        [set9 setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.f green:102/255.f blue:102/255.f alpha:1.f]];
        [dataSets addObject:set9];
    }

    }


     if (count>0) {

        BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc]initWithDataSets:dataSets];
        [data setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.f]];
        [data setValueFormatter:[[LargeValueFormatter alloc] init]];


        // specify the width each bar should have
        data.barWidth = barWidth;

        // restrict the x-axis range
        _chartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = startYear;

        // groupWidthWithGroupSpace(...) is a helper that calculates the width each group needs based on the provided parameters
        _chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = startYear + [data groupWidthWithGroupSpace:groupSpace barSpace: barSpace] * groupCount;

         _chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter=self;

        [data groupBarsFromX: startYear groupSpace: groupSpace barSpace: barSpace];
         //(0.2 + 0.03) * 4 + 0.08
    _chartView.data = data;
     }
    }
}
```