# iOS In Multiple bar chart Unable to set Values more than 4 bar in under given year

Tags: ios, charts

In multiple bar charts, I want to show 9 bars per group. But if the number of bars count increases beyond four, the bars exceeds to next group. Please help me on this.

This is the calculation based on 4 bars in group..

```
float groupSpace = 0.08f;
float barSpace = 0.03f;
float barWidth = 0.2f;
(0.2 + 0.03) * 4 + 0.08 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"
```

Here the above calculation was 4 bars but I don't know the float value for 9 bars, what ever value I changed means finally I want to get interval is 1.00 but I unable to make correct values..

Here I sent the Image Screenshot of Chart Based with 6 Bars..

[image]

Comment: Check this function for grouped bar chart: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44110057

Comment: Thank you Bro, already I done it the same way. Thanks for your response..